HELP! I thought this was an easy request but nothing is easy with Salesforce!
I swear every time I get a request from a user that seems simple, it NEVER is! haha
I have a use case of when a record is created or updated, I need the flow to check if 8 fields have been updated and if they were, send out an email to the user in the field(s) that were updated.
The entry criteria is one place where I'm struggling...these fields can't be required so I have no way of knowing which of the 8 fields will be filled out upon record creation but yet I also need it to trigger if only one field's value is changed after the record is created...
I tried (1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4 AND 5 AND 6 AND 7 AND 8) OR (1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4 OR 5 OR 6 OR 7 OR 8) but that didn't work...
I also tried the formula below that might work but it only works for one field, not sure how to nest formulas to do the same for all 8 fields...
(isnew() && !isnull( BD_Lead__c )) || ischanged( BD_Lead__c )
Any ideas guys?

You're thinking about this the wrong way. You can break a big problem down into smaller problems that are easier to solve. Instead of one big Decision, make 8 or more smaller Decisions. If you want to mark which fields changed in the email, this makes it easy to build up an email body with the changes tailored to which field(s) changed.  Otherwise, it can just make it easier to read and manage. You can also use multiple Outcomes instead of just one Outcome, following the same method. Each Outcome checks just one field, and will be linked to a common Send Email component.
As far as why you're having problems with the formula is that you don't seem to fully understand AND and OR. The formula would be:
(ISNEW() && NOT(ISNULL(Field1) && ISNULL(Field2) && ...) ||
(NOT(ISNEW()) && (ISCHANGED(Field1) || ISCHANGED(Field2) || ...)

Note that NOT(A && B) is the same as NOT(A) || NOT(B) (see de Morgan's Laws), which saves the formula from looking more like (ISNEW() && (NOT(ISNULL(Field1) || NOT(ISNULL(Field2) || ... ), which is much more difficult to read.
But again, you can simply write a ton of formulas to break up the problem. For example, you could have each formula simply read (ISNEW() && NOT(ISNULL(Field1)) || ISCHANGED(Field1), then chain them all together in another formula: {!Field1Check} || {!Field2Check} || ....
There are many ways to approach this problem, it just takes a bit of mental exercise to get there. Use flows and formulas often enough, and you'll soon be an expert at it.
